# Can my backpropagation implementation be correct although gradient checking returns different gradients for specific inputs?

Tags: neural-network, f#, backpropagation

Has been a while since I last asked a question here so if there's anything wrong or missing please kindly point it out and I try to adress it! :)

So my problem in short is that for specific edge cases the gradients calculated by my backpropgation algorithm are not nearly equal to the numerical calculated gradients.

**Further information**

At the end you can find my whole implementation of the neuronal network and backpropagation with the specific functions possibly being wrong called calcDeltas2D & calcDeltasAndAdjustments (I'm working on good naming).

In calcDeltas2D just the deltas for backpropagation are calculated and then in calcDeltasAndAdjustments the results of that function is used to compute the final adjustments (without learning rate).

The code includes tests using Expecto as test library. In each test the results of running backpropagation are compared to numerical gradients.
The first 3 Tests are using random inputs & random weights in various network architecture combinations (trying to cover all cases). These tests succeed most of the time (even with an epsilon which is lower than 1e-1 :) ).
The last test case is using a constant for all neurons & random weights. This test is the one which fails most of the time (it appears that the random weights have an influence on the outcome here).

**Code:**

This can be run with .NET 5 smoothly via `dotnet fsi PathToThisCodeFile.fsx`.

```ml
#r "nuget: MathNet.Numerics"
#r "nuget: MathNet.Numerics.FSharp"
#r "nuget: Expecto"

open MathNet.Numerics

let randomDoubles =
    Random.Random.doubles
    >> Array.map (fun v -> 1.0 - v * 2.0)

let randomDecimals = randomDoubles >> Array.map decimal

module Array2D =

    let inline zip arr1 arr2 =
        arr1
        |> Array2D.mapi (fun i j e1 -> (e1, Array2D.get arr2 i j))

    let inline toSeq (arr: 'a [,]) =
        seq {
            for i = 0 to Array2D.length1 arr - 1 do
                for j = 0 to Array2D.length2 arr - 1 do
                    yield arr.[i, j]
        }

let sigmaFun value = 1.0 / (1.0 + (exp (-float value)))

[<AutoOpen>]
module NN2D =
    type Node = decimal [,]

    type Layer = Node [,]

    type Network2D = { layers: Layer [] }

    type LayerResult =
        { activation: decimal [,]
          intervalues: decimal [,] list }

    type PositionNetwork = { layer: int; node: int * int }

    type CNN =
        { filterMatrices: decimal [,] []
          network: Network2D }

    let getValues2D (inputX: decimal [,]) (network: Network2D) sigmaFun =
        network.layers
        |> Array.fold
            (fun (state: LayerResult) nodes ->
                let activation = state.activation
                let ls = state.intervalues

                let res: decimal [,] =
                    nodes
                    |> Array2D.map
                        (fun weights ->
                            Array2D.zip activation weights
                            |> Array2D.map (fun (a, b) -> a * b)
                            |> Array2D.toSeq
                            |> Seq.sort
                            |> Seq.sum
                            |> sigmaFun)

                { LayerResult.activation = res
                  LayerResult.intervalues = List.append ls [ res ] })
            { LayerResult.activation = inputX
              LayerResult.intervalues = [] }

    let calcDeltas2D (inputX: decimal [,]) network sigmaFun (expected: decimal [,]): decimal [,] [] * LayerResult =
        let layerResult = getValues2D inputX network sigmaFun
        let lastLayerIndex = network.layers.Length - 1

        let deltas: decimal [,] [] =
            [| for layer in network.layers -> Array2D.zeroCreate (Array2D.length1 layer) (Array2D.length2 layer) |]

        layerResult.intervalues.[lastLayerIndex]
        |> Array2D.iteri
            (fun j1 j2 o_j -> deltas.[lastLayerIndex].[j1, j2] <- (o_j - expected.[j1, j2]) * (o_j * (1.0m - o_j)))

        for layer in lastLayerIndex - 1 .. -1 .. 0 do
            layerResult.intervalues.[layer]
            |> Array2D.iteri
                (fun j1 j2 o_j ->
                    let deltaSum =
                        let upperLayer = layer + 1

                        layerResult.intervalues.[upperLayer]
                        |> Array2D.mapi
                            (fun l1 l2 _ ->
                                let delta_l = deltas.[upperLayer].[l1, l2]

                                let w_jl =
                                    network.layers.[upperLayer].[l1, l2].[j1, j2]

                                delta_l * w_jl)
                        |> Array2D.toSeq
                        |> Seq.sort
                        |> Seq.sum

                    let delta_j = deltaSum * (o_j * (1.0m - o_j))
                    deltas.[layer].[j1, j2] <- delta_j)

        deltas, layerResult

    let calcDeltasAndAdjustments (input: decimal [,]) (network) sigmaFun (expected: decimal [,]) =
        let deltasBeforePoolingLayer, layerResult =
            calcDeltas2D input network sigmaFun expected

        let intervalues =
            input :: layerResult.intervalues |> List.toArray

        network.layers
        |> Array.take (Array.length intervalues - 1)
        |> Array.mapi
            (fun layerNumber nodes ->
                nodes
                |> Array2D.mapi
                    (fun j1 j2 weights ->
                        weights
                        |> Array2D.mapi
                            (fun i1 i2 _ ->
                                deltasBeforePoolingLayer.[layerNumber].[j1, j2]
                                * intervalues.[(layerNumber - 1) + 1].[i1, i2]))),
        layerResult

    open Expecto
    open Expecto.Logging
    open Expecto.Logging.Message

    let private _tests =
        let sigmaFun (value: decimal) =
            1.0 / (1.0 + (exp (-float value))) |> decimal

        let logger = Log.create "2D NN Tests"

        testList
            "2-Dimensional NN functionality tests"
            [ let compareGradients
                network
                input
                (expectedValues: decimal [,])
                (adjustments: decimal [,] [,] [])
                logging
                =
                  network.layers
                  |> Array.mapi
                      (fun layerNumber nodes ->
                          nodes
                          |> Array2D.mapi
                              (fun j1 j2 weights ->
                                  Array2D.zip adjustments.[layerNumber].[j1, j2] weights
                                  |> Array2D.mapi
                                      (fun i1 i2 (adjustment, weight) ->
                                          let calcNetworkWithWeightAdjustment epsilon =
                                              let weights = network.layers.[layerNumber].[j1, j2]
                                              let oldWeight = weight
                                              let res1 = getValues2D input network sigmaFun
                                              weights.[i1, i2] <- oldWeight + epsilon
                                              let res = getValues2D input network sigmaFun

                                              if logging then
                                                  eventX
                                                      $"weight: %A{(i1, i2)}, value: {oldWeight}, res: %A{res.activation}, {
                                                                                                                                res1.activation = res.activation
                                                      }"
                                                  |> logger.info

                                              weights.[i1, i2] <- oldWeight

                                              let acc =
                                                  res.activation
                                                  |> Array2D.mapi
                                                      (fun g h activation ->
                                                          (expectedValues.[g, h] - activation)
                                                          * (expectedValues.[g, h] - activation))
                                                  |> Array2D.toSeq
                                                  |> Seq.sort
                                                  |> Seq.sum

                                              0.5m * acc

                                          let numericalGradient =
                                              let epsilons = [| 99399e-5m |]
                                              if logging then printfn "%A" epsilons
                                              let avgEpsilon = epsilons |> Array.average

                                              let calcNetworkWithShiftedWeightMultipleEpsilons epsilons negate =
                                                  let transform = if negate then fun e -> -e else id

                                                  epsilons
                                                  |> Array.averageBy
                                                      (fun e ->
                                                          let res =
                                                              transform e |> calcNetworkWithWeightAdjustment

                                                          res)

                                              let res1, res2 =
                                                  calcNetworkWithShiftedWeightMultipleEpsilons epsilons false,
                                                  calcNetworkWithShiftedWeightMultipleEpsilons epsilons true

                                              let a =
                                                  match (res1 - res2) with
                                                  | 0.m -> 1e-20m
                                                  | value -> value

                                              (a) / (2.0m * avgEpsilon)

                                          let dist =
                                              abs (adjustment - numericalGradient)
                                              / (abs adjustment + abs numericalGradient)
                                          if logging && dist > 1.0e-1m then
                                              eventX
                                                  $"calculated gradient: {adjustment}, numerical gradient: {
                                                                                                                numericalGradient
                                                  }, dist: {dist}"
                                              |> logger.info

                                          dist <= 1.0e-1m)))

              test "Check that Calculated gradients are nearly equal to the numerical gradients | Single Node in all Layers" {
                  let input =
                      randomDecimals 1 |> Array.singleton |> array2D

                  let network =
                      { Network2D.layers =
                            [| array2D [| [| array2D [| randomDecimals input.Length |] |] |]
                               array2D [| [| array2D [| randomDecimals 1 |> Array.map decimal |] |] |] |] }

                  let expectedValues =
                      randomDecimals 1 |> Array.singleton |> array2D

                  let adjustments, _ =
                      calcDeltasAndAdjustments input network sigmaFun expectedValues

                  let expected =
                      network.layers
                      |> Array.map (Array2D.map (Array2D.map (fun _ -> true)))

                  let actual =
                      compareGradients network input expectedValues adjustments false

                  Expect.sequenceEqual actual expected "gradients"
              }

              test "Check that Calculated gradients are nearly equal to the numerical gradients | Single Node only in last layer" {
                  let input = array2D [| randomDecimals 10 |]
                  let innerLayerSize = 3

                  let network =
                      { Network2D.layers =
                            [| Array2D.init
                                innerLayerSize
                                innerLayerSize
                                (fun _ _ -> array2D [| randomDecimals <| Array2D.length2 input |])
                               array2D [| [| array2D [| for _ in 0 .. innerLayerSize - 1 ->
                                                            randomDecimals innerLayerSize |] |] |] |] }

                  let expectedValues =
                      randomDecimals 1 |> Array.singleton |> array2D

                  let adjustments, _ =
                      calcDeltasAndAdjustments input network sigmaFun expectedValues

                  let expected =
                      network.layers
                      |> Array.map (Array2D.map (Array2D.map (fun _ -> true)))

                  let actual =
                      compareGradients network input expectedValues adjustments false

                  Expect.sequenceEqual actual expected "gradients"
              }

              test "Check that Calculated gradients are nearly equal to the numerical gradients | Multi Node in all Layers" {
                  let input = array2D [| randomDecimals 10 |]
                  let innerLayerSize = 3

                  let network =
                      { Network2D.layers =
                            [| Array2D.init
                                innerLayerSize
                                innerLayerSize
                                (fun _ _ -> array2D [| randomDecimals <| Array2D.length2 input |])
                               array2D [| [| for _ in 0 .. innerLayerSize - 1 ->
                                                 array2D [| for _ in 0 .. innerLayerSize - 1 ->
                                                                randomDecimals innerLayerSize |] |] |] |] }

                  let expectedValues =
                      randomDecimals innerLayerSize
                      |> Array.singleton
                      |> array2D

                  let adjustments, _ =
                      calcDeltasAndAdjustments input network sigmaFun expectedValues

                  let expected =
                      network.layers
                      |> Array.map (Array2D.map (Array2D.map (fun _ -> true)))

                  let actual =
                      compareGradients network input expectedValues adjustments false

                  Expect.sequenceEqual actual expected "gradients"
              }

              test "regression 1" {
                  let input = Array2D.create 1 5 -0.2m
                  let expectedValues = array2D [ [ 1.0m ] ]

                  let network =
                      let layer1X = 5
                      let layer1Y = 1

                      let layers =
                          [| Array2D.create layer1X layer1Y
                             <| array2D (Array.init 1 (fun _ -> randomDecimals 5))
                             Array2D.create 1 1
                             <| array2D (Array.init layer1X (fun _ -> randomDecimals layer1Y)) |]

                      { layers = layers }

                  let adjustments, _ =
                      calcDeltasAndAdjustments input network sigmaFun expectedValues

                  let expected =
                      network.layers
                      |> Array.map (Array2D.map (Array2D.map (fun _ -> true)))

                  let actual =
                      compareGradients network input expectedValues adjustments true

                  Expect.sequenceEqual actual expected "gradients"
              } ]
        |> runTestsWithCLIArgs [] [||]
```

Comment: If your implementation passes with random data a significant proportion of the time, it's probably correct. More likely you are running into the fact that the network itself is not differentiable and random data will inevitably find some points of non-differentiability, so comparing to a numerical derivative at these points will fail.